# LoadRunner - Error 26616/HTTP error 415 in VuGen playback - json

Tags: json, loadrunner

I'm trying to generate a test script for a website that involves creating an item in a database using json, and then later editing that item.  However, I'm having trouble in playback - both action (creating and editing) throw a loadrunner error -26616/ HTTP error 415 (aka 'unsupported file type').

Codesnippet below:

```
web_custom_request("432021234_2", 
    "URL=THEWEBSITE", 
    "Method=PUT", 
    "Resource=0", 
    "RecContentType=application/json", 
    "Referer=THEWEBSITE", 
    "Snapshot=t368.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML", 
    "Body={\"id\":432021234,\"name\":\"PERFORMANCETEST3\",\"stockpileBuildName\":\"YD-SP-PERFORMANCETEST3.0001\",\"stockingAreaId\":\"YD-AR-AREA003\",\"stockingAreaName\":\"Ramps\",\"description\":\"perftest\",\"stockpileType\":\"PRE_CRUSH_STOCKPILE\",\"locationId\":-2083,\"locationName\":\"YD-SP-PERFORMANCETEST3\",\"uniqueShortName\":\"YD.PERFORMANCETEST3\",\"locationStatus\":\"INACTIVE\",\"buildNumber\":1,\"startDate\":\"2019-11-11T14:10:53+08:00\",\"buildStatus\":\"Active\",\"effectiveDate\":\""
    "2019-11-11T14:12:25+08:00\",\"productName\":\"YNDWASTE\",\"productType\":\"WASTE\",\"materialTypeId\":\"WS\",\"materialTypeName\":\"Waste\",\"materialSubTypeId\":\"CW\",\"estTonnes\":0,\"accTonnes\":0,\"adjustmentTonnes\":0,\"railableTonnes\":0,\"pctSampled\":0,\"stockpileCapacity\":9001,\"avaliableStackingSpace\":0,\"carryForwardTonnes\":0,\"scadaBuildStatus\":\"UNKNOWN\",\"quarantinedFlag\":false,\"locationAccessTypeId\":\"DEAD\",\"locationAccessTypeName\":\"Dead\",\"blendingAlgorithm\":\"WAG\"," "\"autoBuildEnabled\":false,\"inPit\":false,\"stockpilePurposeId\":\"DUMP\",\"stockpilePurposeName\":\"Dump\",\"stockpilePurposeSubTypeId\":\"FR\",\"stockpilePurposeSubTypeName\":\"Fill Ramp\",\"locationBuildType\":\"BUILD_DESTROY\",\"lastUpdatedTime\":\"2019-11-11T14:11:28+08:00\",\"lastUpdatedUser\":\"MESDIMSUI\",\"notificationWarnCount\":0,\"notificationErrCount\":0,\"autoCreated\":false,\"comments\":\"performance test edit\",\"hashKey\":\"Et7OqN9EP9OVj04Vq60dLQ==\"}", 
                                LAST);
```

Cursory googling has suggested changing the RecContentType to text/html and adding in a 'EncType=application/json' line underneath it, which changed the error to 26622/409.  I don't know if that is a step towards fixing the problem, or just swapping out one error for another.

I am very very new to loadrunner and to performance testing in general, so please use simple terms :P

Comment: "I am very very new to loadrunner and to performance testing in general."   Have you been through product training and are you working with an assigned mentor?

Comment: @James - I am working with the only other person I know of in our business that does load testing...she's stumped too, by the way. She taught me what she knows about LoadRunner, but she learned on-the-job herself from a contractor we had in briefly (before I was hired).

Comment: Hi Alex, if you are not coming from C background and just starting with LoadRunner I strongly suggest you use the TruWeb protocol to develop your script.

Comment: I have some C++/# experience, used it in a couple units at uni, but that was several years ago so I'm back to googling for nearly everything.  I'll try out TruWeb :)

Comment: You need actual training.   You need an actual mentor for a period.   The stronger your foundation skills, the shorter the internship period.  This is the path to success which is proven to work.   If you cannot find performance issues without a performance test, then you are unlikely to be able to find them with a performance test, for the test tool will only automate the items that you would normally exercise and collect to diagnose issues

Comment: I don't disagree, but I don't have the pull to get more training from work, nor the financials to go get it myself.  It is what it is.

Comment: if your application has enough risk to require performance testing, then a single hour of downtime or reduced performance will financially dwarf by several orders of magnitude the cost of actual training and mentor for your project.  You can find daily the results of decisions like this on the #DailyDamned feed of website crashes under load on twitter

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try correlate `Et7OqN9EP9OVj04Vq60dLQ==` in `\"hashKey\":\"Et7OqN9EP9OVj04Vq60dLQ==\`